# Frequentists tests to check for normality

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, quantile

Let $X_1,...,X_n\sim X$ be $n$ i.i.d. random variables. I want to to test if they follow a normal distribution, in other words, check if their distribution belongs to the Gaussian family.

These are the tests I'm considering:

- Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
- Kolmogorov-Lilliefors test

With these two tests I can statistically test the hypothesis that my data was sampled from a normal distribution. Further tests for univariate normality I've found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test#Frequentist_tests). I would also like to check for normality visually (with QQ-Plots and histograms), which raises the question,

Is a normal QQ-test a valid way to test for normality?

This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278330/durbin-watson-test-and-how-to-do-normal-q-q-plot-and-normal-p-p-plot) refers to the normal QQ-test, so perhaps someone could confirm if it's legit to use.

And is QQ-Plot the same as a normal QQ-test or am I confusing concepts here?

Comment: Any link to online material discussing normal QQ-tests is more than welcome.

Comment: Try also ask Cross Validated (Stats StackExchange)

Comment: Valid point @BenjaminWang should I post the same question there? And would you be able to provide some feedback here?

Comment: @nimen55290 Can confirm normal QQ "test" in linked post means normal QQ plot.